# Which question has most bounty ever set on it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I just came across this question on SO 
[Using a piano keyboard as a computer keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928061/using-a-piano-keyboard-as-a-computer-keyboard) by someone named [l--''''''---------''''''''''''](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117700/l). I was actually reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478947/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-artificial-neural-networks) on SO and happened to see his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478947/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-artificial-neural-networks#comment3139397_478947) on the question, drawn probably by his (could be her :) ) peculiar name. I visited his profile and saw that piano question. Out of curiosity I went to see its edit history, and good lord, I counted a total of 13 bounties set on it over time!

> 500*11 + 100*1 + 50*1 = 5650

See [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5928061/revisions).

Not all bounties came from the OP though. Is this the question on the entire SO with the maximum bounties ever to be be set on it (either by the OP or anyone else)? If not then which is?

---

#### Still to be answered:

I also noticed that that user has set over 12000 of valuable reps on bounties. Is this the maximum, though I believe not, for any user to ever spend on bounties? What change do I need to make to that query, if that will work, to get what I want?

Comment: Meta duplicate: [Which answer has the most bounty points awarded to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269076)

Comment: @DavidPostill My question doesn't ask about which *answer* has most bounty, but it asks about which *question* has most bounty set on it. Read the question first.

Comment: @Ian same goes for you too: I am talking about which *question*, not *answer*. Additionally, I am talking about SO, though I would welcome anything *in addition to SO*.

Comment: @Shadowfax modify the queries from those answers.  (IIRC you can use `where postType = 1` for questions).

Comment: @ryanyuyu which answers? Can you give the link?

Comment: @Shadowfax the answers to the links others have already provided.  But [rene's MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269006/what-question-has-had-the-most-bounties-on-it/269010#269010) is very close to what you want.

Comment: @ryanyuyu never mind. I began working on that already, just a short while after the last comment. :) And you can add that as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the gem :) The question I cited is the one with most bounty set on it. I ran the query found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269010/282546).

[image: query results]